# Calculate the cosine similarity between vectors segregating the pairs from a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as the following below:

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.spatial.distance as ssd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'SJDR': [2,3,7,8,0,0], 'TR': [0,0,0,1,1,3], 'BSO': [1,1,2,0,1,1], 'CLASS': [2,2,1,3,1,3]})
df
```

and I calculate the similarity between each line like this:

```
1 - ssd.cosine(df.iloc[0].to_numpy(), df.iloc[1].to_numpy())
```

However, I need to select the vectors to be calculated must be selected according to the `CLASS` column. So I need to calculate the cosine similarity of the vectors of one class with all the others. For this dataset, I would have to do the following calculations according to the `CLASS` column:

```
Ex.: 
Class 1 Vectors x Class 1 Vectors 
Class 1 Vectors x Class 2 Vectors 
Class 1 Vectors x Class 3 Vectors
Class 2 Vectors x Class 3 Vectors
```

So far I can't think of a way to do this. Can anyone help?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Do just want the cosine similarity matrix of df? with `from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity` you can use `cosine_similarity(df)` for the whole matrix.

Comment: The output can be a dictionary or dataframe that contains the similarity of cosine between different class column values.